# repeat the icons in the Internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, icons, png

I'm developing a website (using php by the way) and I'm having a problem with IE6,7,8.

my (www.sanatkadeh.com) icons in first page that those are png files,repeat in the background (if you want to know what I mean,please visit my website with IE6,7,8 )

is there some CSS or jquery codesto solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in IE 7, & 9 & don't see your issue.
It may be a cause of different browser culture settings or something else.

But I do see your HTML:

```
<a href="http://list.sanatkadeh.com">
 <h2 style="background-image:url(template/Theme/images/comments.png);">مرجع صنعت کده</h2>
</a>
```

Try setting no-repeat in your style.

```
 <a href="http://list.sanatkadeh.com">
    <h2 style="background-image:url(template/Theme/images/comments.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;">مرجع صنعت کده</h2>
 </a>
```